# Smooth structure on a connected sum

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I'm struggling with the following problem (J.Lee p.246, problem 9-12)

Suppose $M_1$ and $M_2$ are connected smooth $n$-manifolds and $M_1 \# M_2$ is their smooth connected sum. Show that the smooth structure on $M_1 \# M_2$ can be chosen in such a way that there are open subsets $\tilde M_1, \tilde M_2 \subset M_1 \# M_2$ that are diffeomorphic to $M_1 \setminus \{p_1\}$ and $M_2 \setminus \{p_2\}$, respectively, such that $\tilde M_1 \cup \tilde M_2 = M_1 \# M_2$ and $\tilde M_1 \cap \tilde M_2 \simeq (-1, 1) \times S^{n-1}$.

First I tried to glue the boundary charts of $M_1$ and $M_2$, by considering their image under the coordinate maps as an open sets in $\mathbb{H}^n$ and $-\mathbb{H}^n$, respectively. I can do this by taking boundary coordinate balls, however, I think it is not guaranteed that such union of coordinate balls becomes a coordinate ball of $M_1 \# M_2$.

So instead of gluing charts, I think I have to extend the boundary charts somehow. But it is just a rough idea and I don't see how to proceed. For the interior charts, I think I don't have to modify them because we already have smooth compatibility there.

Any help will be appreciated very much.

Edit: The interior/boundary charts means the ones in $M_1 - U_1$ and $M_2 - U_2$.

Comment: Aren't $M_1$ and $M_2$ are manifolds without boundary?

Comment: @Kajelad Yes they are, but we have to consider $M_1 - U_1$ and $M_2 - U_2$ where $U_1, U_2$ are charts of $M_1, M_2$, respectively. John Lee defines a connected sum as a smooth manifold without boundary obtained by attaching those two manifolds with boundary, along their diffeomorphic boundaries.

Comment: Indeed, though $U_1$, and $U_2$ should be open balls, not chart domains. Rather than using boundary charts, try choosing charts around $p_1\in M_1$ and $p_2\in M_2$ and cutting out the unit ball from each.

Comment: @Kajelad OMG you're right. I had a misunderstanding on definition. Thanks for advice.